# Weird behavior with recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, control-flow

I have this code:

```
    public void myFunction(String label, String type, string command, int attempts = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Utility.Logger("myFunction attempt " + attempts.ToSafeString() + " label " + label + " type " + type, command);
            ...stuff...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (attempts < 10)
                return myFunction(label, type, command, attempts++);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have a recursive call in the catch branch, where I set a parameter a counter = counter + 1.

The weird point is I have always attempts = 0 in my log. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you actually falling into catch? And even if you do every time you go in there attempts value is reset zero you passing in..

Comment: `attempts++` will return _old_ value and then increment value by 1. So you are always passing 0 to your recursive function. Change that to `++attempts` or better not use this in such context and just increment outside the function call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`attempts++` increments `attempts` *afterwards*, `++attempts` does it *before* recursing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `attempts++` to `++attempts`.

UPD: oops, took too long.